# Really Simple Re Weighting Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I am having a major brain cramp and cannot remember how to to this.

In a perfect world I have 7 types of activities that I could have participated in.  These 7 activities each have a weight that add up to 100.

But I have some records that only participated in 2 activities, or 3 activities.  So I need to re-weight the values I have to add up to 100%.

For example activity A and B are present and have values of .51048 and .16977  -  what formula do I use to re-weight these add up  100%

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

$$ \text{weight A} = \frac{\text{weight A}}{\text{weight A} + \text{weight B}}$$

in your case

$$ \text{weight A} = \frac{.51048}{.51048  + .16977} = 0.75043 $$

This generalizes in a natural way to reweighting 3, 4, 5, or 6 events: you just put more of the weights on the bottom of the fraction.